# sharepoint workflow on a task item not starting

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, task

I have the following scenario:

- a workflow is associated with an item list
- this workflow creates various tasks for different people
- since it is quite complex to monitor dueDate for each task item in this workflow, I
  thought I'd create a new workflow that would be associated with the task list and have very simple logic in it, just for emailing when a dueDate approaches on a task

However (of course with Sharepoint, there is always an however!), although I can associate the second workflow to a task list of the first workflow, it does not start automatically, 
Nor can I start them manually, as there is even no Workflows item on the ECB menu for these kinds of tasks.

It does work on a normal Task content type, just not on the content type that I use for my workflow tasks. My content type derives from the Sharepoint task content type.

Update: I've tried adding a workflow to the content type itself and then I get this error:
"Workflows may not be associated with content types whose base is on 'WorkflowTask'"

Any ideas why this is or any workarounds?

Update: according to article on office.microsoft.com - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102376561033.aspx#2 this should be possible:

> "For example, suppose that each time a
>   new document is added to your
>   Documents for Review library, a
>   workflow running on that library
>   creates a task to review the document
>   in your Tasks list. You can create a
>   secondary workflow on the Tasks list
>   that sets a value in the Due Date
>   field of each of those new tasks. "

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a hardcoded limitation to me. This kind of parallel approach is indeed very complicated in SharePoint, try having a secondary list to sync all the tasks (add new items to that list when a task is completed while also changing something on the original item) and the original item will have a *OnChange* type of behavior to check if all the fired tasks are completed and/or what tasks are close to the due date.

Comment: well, I found this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA102376561033.aspx#2 which suggests it should be possible? Even though this is in Sharepoint designer?

Comment: The link explains a workflow started by your primary workflow, it is not related on attaching it to the workflow library. But the link is useful, try the concepts in it

Comment: actually, I think it is exactly what I am trying to achieve: 
"Create a workflow attached to the Tasks list that starts automatically when a new item is created." 
But perhaps this is what the issue is: 
"A secondary workflow that is designed in Office SharePoint Designer 2007 can only be triggered by the actions of another workflow that was also designed in Office SharePoint Designer 2007 — and not by one of the predefined workflows included with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007, or by a custom workflow created in Visual Studio. Also note that even if a workflow was designed in Office

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2007, its actions will still not trigger a secondary workflow if the user who started the workflow has signed in by using the system account. A workflow running under the system account cannot trigger a secondary workflow.

Comment: This happened after SP1 yes (system account not triggering workflows), not even a primary one will function properly.

Answer (score 1):

A workflow running under the system account cannot trigger a secondary workflow. This was Security Fix given in SP1

This is the problem, believe me, I faced it :)...

Hope this helps...